# Can't access Apache2 on a VPS via public IP of the server from an external computer

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian, apache-http-server, iptables

```
root@Client13:/etc/apache2# netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      104129/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      65242/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      65242/sshd: /usr/sb
root@Client13:/etc/apache2#
```

Apache is running and listening on port 80. I can connect to the page using curl or wget from the machine that's running Apache2, but when I try to connect to the public IP address from another computer, it doesn't work and I cannot access the page.

Note:
OS: Debian 11
UFW is not installed
All IP tables rules are flushed i.e. iptables is not blocking anything
I can connect on TCP port 22 via SSH using the same public IP but when running Apache2, I cannot access it on port 80 of the same IP.

Output of iptables -L -n:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Output of nmap ip -p80,443 -Pn

```
Nmap scan report for public (x.x.x.x)
Host is up.

PORT    STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp  filtered http
443/tcp filtered https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.08 seconds
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134880/discussion-on-question-by-floyd-cant-access-apache2-on-a-vps-via-public-ip-of-t).